# How to calculate weighted (grayscale) centroids of pixel clusters contained within bounding boxes on an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, grayscale, centroid

I've written some code in MATLAB that converts an image (of stars) into a grayscale image and then into a binary image using a set threshold and then labels each cluster of pixels (stars) that is above this threshold. The labelling produces an output:
e.g.

```matlab
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0
 0 0 0 3 3 0 2 0 0
 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0]
```

So each cluster of 1's, 2's, 3's etc. represents a star. After this the code then finds the centroids of each pixel cluster and draws a bounding box around each centroid (centered on the centroid) with an 8 x 8 pixel area. The bounding box limits are made by finding xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin of each calculated centroid, which involves either adding or subtracting 4 (pixels) from the x and y coordinates of each centroid.

The weighted centroid is calculated like so:

x_coordinate_centroid = sum(x_coordinate .* pixel_values) / sum_pixel_values
y_coordinate_centroid = sum(y_coordinate .* pixel_values) / sum_pixel_values

x/y_coordinate and pixel values are for the pixels contained within each bounding box.

The bounding box would surround an 8 x 8 pixel area (with the given intensities) on the grayscale image such as:

```matlab
[100 100 100 90  20  20  0   0
 80  90  100 90  20  30  0   0
 50  70  100 70  30  0   20  0
 50  0   0   60  30  30  0   0
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   50  0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   40  0   0   0   0   0   0
 0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

The top left value ([xmin, ymax]), for example, could have image coordinates [41, 14] and an intensity of 100.

The output from my code, for example, could give 5 bounding boxes across the grayscale image. I now need to write code that automatically calculates the weighted centroid of each bounding box region. I'm not sure how to go about this, does anyone have any ideas how this can be achieved?

My code for calculating the centroids and their bounding boxes is shown below.

```matlab
%% Calculate centroids of each labelled pixel cluster within binary image

N = max(B(:));    % total number of pixel labels generated in output array
sum_total = zeros(N,1);    % create N x 1 array of 0's
sum_yv = zeros(N,1);    % "
sum_xv = zeros(N,1);    % "
for xx=1:size(B,2)    % search through y positions
   for yy=1:size(B,1)    % search through x positions
      index = B(yy,xx);
      if index>0
          sum_total(index) = sum_total(index) + 1;
          sum_yv(index) = sum_yv(index) + yy;
          sum_xv(index) = sum_xv(index) + xx;
      end
   end
end
centroids = [sum_xv, sum_yv] ./ sum_total;    % calculates centroids for each cluster


x_lower_limits = centroids(:,1)-4;
y_lower_limits = centroids(:,2)+4;    % lower on image means larger y coord number
x_upper_limits = centroids(:,1)+4;
y_upper_limits = centroids(:,2)-4;    % higher on image means lower y coord number


x_lower_limits(x_lower_limits<1)=1;    % limit smallest x coord to image axis (1,y)
y_lower_limits(y_lower_limits>size(binary_image,1))=size(binary_image,1);    % limit largest y coord to image axis (x,517)
x_upper_limits(x_upper_limits>size(binary_image,2))=size(binary_image,2);    % limit largest x coord to image axis (508,y)
y_upper_limits(y_upper_limits<1)=1;    % limit smallest y coord to image axis (x,1)


width = x_upper_limits(:,1) - x_lower_limits(:,1);    % width of bounding box
height = y_lower_limits(:,1) - y_upper_limits(:,1);    % height of bounding box


hold on

for xl=1:size(x_lower_limits,1)
               r(xl)=rectangle('Position',[x_lower_limits(xl,1) y_upper_limits(xl,1) width(xl,1) height(xl,1)],'EdgeColor','r');


end
for i=1:size(centroids,1)
    plot(centroids(i,1),centroids(i,2),'rx','MarkerSize',10)
end
hold off


%%
```

Comment: I haven't gone through it all, but this is a **lot** of code for just calculating the centroid of an 8x8 window. Are you sure this is a [mcve]?

Comment: Well I can remove some code but then you would have to create your own code to create a binary image and to label the pixel clusters. I'm fairly new to this forum so I have no idea what I should class as the minimum code.

Comment: Well, what are the inputs to calculating the weighted centroid? (In this case, I would expect it to be a sample grayscale image and the corresponding labeled image.) What code have you tried to get the centroid of one (or more) of the clusters? (The code that got you the labeled image is irrelevant, because it's working correctly, right?) What output did you get? What output did you expect?

Comment: The inputs are the coordinates of every pixel contained within each bounding box area and their individual grayscale intensity value. My issue is I don't know how to go through each coordinate and calculate the weighted centroids for each bounding box. The code to calculate the binary centroids starts on line 65. All the code works correctly but it's all needed to calculate the next step - the grayscale weighted centroids (I assume - but there could be another method).

Comment: So your inputs are your upper and lower limits arrays, and your original grayscale image, right? In your question, we need (small) examples of those. Not the code that got you those inputs, that's just noise, but the actual data we need to work on. Then you need to tell us what precise problem you're having in writing the code for the next step. Are you having problems with indexing the grayscale image? Do you not know the formula for calculating the weighted centroid? Where is your code for this step and how does its output not meet your needs?

Comment: I've updated the question to provide more clarity and reduce the amount of code. Hopefully this is clearer now.